# No server pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have install pgadmin 4 via docker, and run via the following command.

```
docker run -p 5050:80 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=testemail@gmail.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=testpassword" -d  dpage/pgadmin4
```

I have also installed PostgreSQL 13.5

```
postgres@ahmad:~$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.5 (Ubuntu 13.5-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

Now Postgres is running, as we can see

```
postgres=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

And pgadmin is running at http://127.0.0.1:5050/browser;

The problem is that I have no servers showing in servers sidebar, as shown in the Image.

[image]

How should I connect my PostgreSQL with pgadmin4. THanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a PG connection by right-clicking "servers"->create->Server and inputing the credentials to your local Postgres instance.

PGAdmin is only a PG client and doesn't per default create a server configuration for you.